# What's the difference between reading Emgu image from bitmap or path in find contours

Tags: c#, bitmap, contour, emgucv

I'm trying to find contours in the emgu image, but I discover that the number of found contours is not the same if the emgu image read from path or from bitmap.

Example........

```
Image<Bgr, byte> emguPathImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(path);
Image<Gray, byte> gray1 = emguPathImage .Convert<Gray, Byte>();


Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(path);
Image<Bgr, byte> emguBitmapImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmapImage);
Image<Gray, byte> gray2 = emguBitmapImage .Convert<Gray, Byte>();
```

Now when I tried to called findContours for gray1 and gray2, I get different number of contours

```
 var sourceContours1 = gray1.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST);


 var sourceContours2 = gray2.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST);
```

so is that possible to get exactly the same results, but why the results is different!

Comment: I had an issue with EmguCV loading PNG files where the result image was slightly different than loading with the Bitmap class. Have you tried saving the images emguBitmapImage and gray2 to compare them ?